# What is Mr. Bean's full name?

Tags: character, mr-bean

We know Mr. Bean, a British sitcom starring Rowan Atkinson in the title role. But I always wonder what Mr. Bean's full name is. It's never revealed in the series.

Comment: I don't understand the question. His name is "Bean".

Comment: @omegacron you mean like "Cher"?

Comment: @Omegacron Bean is his last name :)

Comment: And here I thought it might be Julian (according to the wiki): http://mrbean.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Bean_(character)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the sitcom itself, his name was never revealed. However, in the sketch for Comic Relief, we learned that his first name was Mr (i.e. Mr. Mr Bean):

We also see his [passport](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bendeck/2639210778/in/photostream/) in the Mr Bean Holiday Movie:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, same first name as Mr. T ("middle name: period")

Comment: So, I've fixed the unpausable GIF and replaced it by an actual video from the movie. We're all going to calm down and enjoy this question and its answers now. No need for huffy counter answers or rollbacks due to supposedly not recognizing Bean in the scene. Be done with it please, everyone!